# Why is an explicit `this` needed to access this STL member?

Tags: c++, std

I decided to write a stupid code that doesn't work:

```
template <class T, class Container>
class reversible_stack : protected std::stack<T, Container>
{
public:
    void reverse()
    {
        std::reverse(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
    }
};
```

`this->c` is needed instead of `c`.

Yet there isn't any `this` needed here:

```
namespace a
{
    class base
    {
        protected:
            int i;
    };
};

class derived : protected a::base
{
public:
    void foo() { i; }
};
```

`__attribute__ ((__visibility__ ("default")))` makes no difference.

You can see [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/libstdc++/api/a01245_source.html) code here. What is the difference that makes `this` required?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate. See the following code:

```
namespace standard
{
    template <typename T>
    class container
    {
        protected:
            int i;
    };

    template <typename T, typename Container = container<T>>
    class base
    {
        protected:
            Container c;
    };
}

class derived : protected standard::base<int>
{
public:
    void foo() { c; }
};
```

Notice how `base` doesn't need to inherit from `container`, just like `stack` doesn't need to inherit from `deque` (container). Yet this [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/918d7bb11bcce36d).

<sup>Somebody is going to say "it's an implementation detail", but the variable name `c` is specified by the standard [23.2.3.1].</sup>

Comment: So, according to you, the first code doesn't compile?

Comment: @jotik It's a protected member of `std::stack` of type container.

Comment: _"name c is specified by the standard [23.2.3.1]"_?!

Comment: @CinCout [Try it yourself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/741564662b8d4a88)

Comment: @ZDF According to the [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/libstdc++/api/a01278_source.html) comment. Without a document number, it's not really easy to look it up because section numbers change. In 23.6.3.1 of N4140: `Container c;`

Comment: Since it gives rise to a class from a definition of a definition based on a definition of a definition, give the compiler a break and throw it a bone here!

Comment: It's because templates!

Comment: If you think that this is a valid statement, you should  provide a link.

Comment: It's late so I can't set it up but it would be an interesting experiment to see if it notices that this->something_thats_not_there is flagged as an error or not before the template is used.

Comment: @user6292850: _"EDIT: This is not a duplicate"_ Yes, it is. Your example code does not adequately match the failing testcase. See this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/663c739b816adfcf A base `standard::base<int>` is not the same as a base `standard::base<someTemplateArgumentHere>`. That is, your failing testcase has base `std::stack<T, Container>`, not base `std::stack<int, Container>`. That's the difference.

Comment: You always use this-> when messing around with templates. Compilers work differently in both cases.To be specific the Type checking is devided into two parts in the template case...before and after the template parameter is known while in the second case it's done all at once.

Comment: (or "not base `std::stack<int, container<int>>`", I should say)